# Javascript - check array if array2 partially ordered as array1

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

How can I achieve this kind of conditions in javascript? (via: **vanilla** or **lodash**)

```
const array1 = [1, 2]
```

```
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4] //true
const array2 = [1, 3, 2, 4] //true
```

```
const array2 = [4, 3, 2, 1] //false
const array2 = [2, 3, 1, 4] //false
```

I tried something like this.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const array1 = [1, 2];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const trimmed = array2.filter((n) => combinations.indexOf(n) > -1);
const isEqual = _.isEqualWith(array1, trimmed);
console.log(isEqual);
```

Please post if you have much cleaner and much flexible code for this problem.

Comment: What if `array2` is `[2, 1, 2]`? Or `[1, 2, 1]`?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add those. That supposed to be false even I have filtered those kind of array beforehand

Comment: Alright so we're going to assume that all elements of the array are unique?

Comment: Yes, they are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.every()` to check if each item in `arr2` is either not included in `arr1` or is found in place `i` (the current index of `arr1`):

```js
const fn = (arr1, arr2) => {
  let i = 0
  
  return arr2.every(v => !arr1.includes(v) || v === arr1[i++])
}

console.log(fn([1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4])) // true
console.log(fn([1, 2], [1, 3, 2, 4])) // true
console.log(fn([1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1])) // false
console.log(fn([1, 2], [2, 3, 1, 4])) // false
```

A variation on this would be to shallow clone the 1st array using destructuring a rest syntax, and then use `Array.shift()` to always check the current 1st item of `arr1`:

```js
const fn = ([...arr1], arr2) => arr2.every(v => !arr1.includes(v) || v === arr1.shift())

console.log(fn([1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4])) // true
console.log(fn([1, 2], [1, 3, 2, 4])) // true
console.log(fn([1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1])) // false
console.log(fn([1, 2], [2, 3, 1, 4])) // false
```

---

With **lodash** - get the intersection of `arr2` and `arr1` (same items, regardless of order), and then check if it's equal to `arr1` (same items, same order):

```js
const fn = (arr1, arr2) => _.isEqual(
  _.intersection(arr2, arr1),
  arr1
)

console.log(fn([1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4])) // true
console.log(fn([1, 2], [1, 3, 2, 4])) // true
console.log(fn([1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1])) // false
console.log(fn([1, 2], [2, 3, 1, 4])) // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering all elements in array1 will be present in array2, you apply two pointer approach.

Something like this:

```js
/** Checks if arr2 is partially ordered as arr1 */
function isOrdered(arr1, arr2) {
  let i = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length && i < arr1.length; j++) {
    if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) i++;
  }

  return i === arr1.length;
}

console.log(isOrdered([1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4])); // true
console.log(isOrdered([1, 2], [1, 3, 2, 4])); // true
console.log(isOrdered([1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1])); // false
console.log(isOrdered([1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1])); // false
```